# how to pass data to a form in another component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form in a seperate component which looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px" >
    <input 
        formControlName="name" 
        type="text"
        placeholder="please enter"
        />
</div>
</form>
```

the ts file looks like this (formcontrol part)

```
 form = this.builder.group({
    name: new FormControl(),
  })
```

this is how I call it from the other component:
component B:

```
 <form></form>
```

What I want to achieve now is the following I am filling some values from my backend which works, I know want to asign these values to my form from the form component. I know I have to use @Input I am kinda stuck against a wall and dont know how to connect them. Can someone give me a small example how I can fill my form from values from component b?

To my knowledge I have posted the most important part of this question, if anything else is needed feel free to ask

UPDATE_
Form.ts

```
@Input()
  myObject: { name: string };

  form = this.builder.group({
      name: new FormControl()
  });

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      if (changes.myObject?.currentValue) {
          this.form.patchValue(this.myObject);
      }
  }
```

UPDATE2:

my form ts looks like this now:

```
   @Input()
    myObject: { name: string };

    form = this.builder.group({
        name: new FormControl()
    });


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.myObject && changes.myObject.currentValue) {
      this.form.patchValue(this.myObject);
    }
  }
```

My form.hml like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px" >
    <input 
        formControlName="name" 
        type="text"
        placeholder="please enter"
        />
</div>
</form
```

my calling component ts like this:

```
this.form.controls.legitimiertePersonNameField.setValue(response.vorname)
      this.someName = this.form.controls.legitimiertePersonNameField.value -> gets the data from formcontrol in parent/calling
```

html from caling looks like this:

```
  <gwg-form [myObject]="someName"></gwg-form>
```

The someName value is correct I could see it in a console.log but it does not set the value for the fomrCOntrol of the form.html it is just empty input

Answer (score 0):

#### form.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-form'
    ...
})
export class FormComponent implements OnChanges {
    
    @Input()
    myObject: { name: string };

    form = this.builder.group({
        name: new FormControl()
    });

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.myObject?.currentValue) {
            this.form.patchValue(this.myObject);
        }
    }
}
```

#### form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 10px" >
    <input 
        formControlName="name" 
        type="text"
        placeholder="please enter" />
  </div>
</form>
```

#### calling.component.ts

```
@Component({ ... })
export class CallingComponent {
    
    someObject: { name: string };

    loadData(): void {
        this.someObject = ...
    }
}
```

#### calling.component.html

```
<my-form [myObject]="someObject">
</my-form>
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the following error:
src/app/module/offers/offer/form.component.ts:77:41 - error TS1005: ':' expected.
Updated code is in the post

Comment: Looks like a syntax error ;) Please provide the source code line (77).

Comment: This was the Source line the Problem was the ngOmChanges if I take out the question mark it works but then it says it can not read the currentvalue

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you currently using? Optional chaining came with version `3.7`. If the `?.` operator does not work for you, simply replace `changes.myObject?.currentValue` by `changes.myObject && changes.myObject.currentValue` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: Hi I updated my code again I still have some problems the field stays empty from my form.component

Comment: any ideas? I even tried to give the formcontrol of the calling component directly but still no luck

Comment: To get it working, the object you pass to `FormComponent` must match the form structure, e.g. `{ name: 'Joe' }`. Are you sure your object is looking like this?